# Canvas export image just image width / height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have this canvas where I draw my image then I draw some other stuff:

http://jsbin.com/haheqorexe/2/edit

```
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height, centerShift_x,centerShift_y,img.width*ratio, img.height*ratio);
```

I want to export this but just the picture viewport like in the following example.

1. Does anybody has some idea how do to this?
2. If the canvas width is 400 can the exported picture be 600px width? (export bigger / highres)

[image]

Comment: You can use canvas methods to copy a rectangle section of one canvas to another, and then export the new canvas. The 2nd canvas can even be "off screen" or display: none for example.

Comment: Thanks man, I was thinking to do like this but I wasnt sure if it is the best practice!

Comment: That's the only way I can think of... This could be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: I endorse @BrianGlaz's idea: Create a second in-memory canvas using `createElement('canvas')` and use the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to draw just the viewport to that in-memory canvas. Then export the dataURL of the in-memory canvas with `inMemoryCanvas.toDataURL()`.